# How to figure out UIControlStateNomal and UIControlStateSeleted in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

The method - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state of UIButton.

Since if you have not set an image for the Selected state, then the Normal image will also appear when the button isSelected.

I mean I want to set image for normal state and only title(no image) for selected?

Sorry my English!

Answer (score 0):

You call `setImage:forState:` as many times as you need:

```
[someButton setImage:someNormalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setImage:someSelectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**Update**: It appears you want a button that shows just an image for the normal state and just a title for the selected state. I don't know if the following will work but give it a try:

```
[someButton setImage:someNormalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[someButton setTitle:@"Some Title" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: if  I want to set image for normal state and only title(no image) for selected?                                                 [myButton setTitle:content forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; do not work too...

Comment: Your apps are awesome!Nice to meet you.I am learning from online video  of Stanford University.

Comment: I am afraid not。[someButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected]; this code seems no effect.The image appears in the Normal state still appears in the selected state and I just want to see the title.Jsut like a card game.The back of a card is an image，and when you flip the card it just shows a string like'3'.It is midnight now,keep working tomorrow.